# How to store data in Json file in Laravel app, and where i write that code?

Tags: json, laravel, stored-procedures, save, datastore

I would like to know how to store my data in json file and retrieve from it, without use database MySQL?

I dont know from where to start

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you done so far? If you've Googled, there's a lot of results there on how to write to a JSON file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) functions.

You can also use Laravel's built-in [Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem) class:

```
$data = [
    "name" => $yourName,
    "title" => $yourTitle
];

// to put file data
Storage::put('filepath/filename.json', json_encode($data));

// to get file data
$contents = Storage::get('filepath/filename.json');
```